# Cast struct from byte buffer

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to read a `struct` from a binary `byte buffer` using `cast` and `pack`.
I was trying to keep track of worst case read time from in memory buffer so I decided to keep a `chrono high resolution clock nano` timer. Whenever the timer increased I printed the value. It gave me a worst case scenario of about 20 micro seconds which was huge considering the size of the struct.
When I measured the average time taken it came out to be ~20 nanoseconds. Then I measured how many times was I breaching 50. And it turns out of the ~20 million times, I was breaching 50 nanoseconds only 500 times.

My question is what can possibly cause this performance fluctuation: average of 20 and worst of 20,000?

Secondly, how can I ensure a constant time performance. I am compiling with -O3 and C++11.

```
 // new approach
 #pragma pack(push, 1)
 typedef struct {
    char a;
    long b, c;
    char d, name[10];
    int e , f;
    char g, h;
    int h, i;
} myStruct;
#pragma pack(pop)


//in function where i am using it


 auto am1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
 myStruct* tmp = (myStruct*)cTemp;
 tmp->name[10] = 0;
 auto am2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
 chrono::duration<long, nano> arM = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(am2 - am1);
 if(arM.count() > maxMPO.count())
 {
     cout << "myStruct read time increased: "  << arM.count() <<     "\n";
 maxMPO = arM;
 }
```

I am using g++4.8 with C++11 and an ubuntu server.

Comment: You need to measure the impact of external factors.

Comment: @Bartek, what external factors? any suggestions on how to go about it?

Comment: Yep, you might try using [a proper benchmarking library](https://github.com/rmartinho/nonius) that will repeat the tests automatically and report that information.

Comment: Removed C tag. If you're "using g++4.8 with c++11" and all those `cout` and `::` things, that has _nothing_ to do with the C language. See http://powerfield-software.com/?p=829 :-)

Comment: You can't ensure constant performance. It's out of your hands -- it's platform dependent, and anything short of a real-time OS won't give you any guarantees. For example, your thread could be preempted at the wrong moment. Actually, even at the hardware level there's room for wild variations -- if the memory isn't loaded into cache, an access from RAM can take quite some time.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz You beat me to it!

Comment: @Cameron, so you think this is a pointless exercise?

Comment: @Naveen: What are you trying to do exactly? Why do you need a maximum time in the nanosecond range for individual memory accesses?

Comment: @NaveenSharma: not pointless, but pretty difficult to assess (and `char name[10]; tmp->name[10] = 0;` isn't helping either)

Comment: @stefaanv, i tried without the tmp->name[10] = 0. The data is receive is not null terminated. and if i don't do it then my name has all weird characters at the end of it. any solutions to it?

Comment: @Cameron, I am building a market simulator for quant testing and this would be my order book handler. Want to keep the processing time minimal and this was my first step to see some kind of benchmarks.

Comment: @Naveen: You mean `tmp->name[9] = 0` (9 is the last valid index of an array of size 10). I think that given your use case the average time is more important than the maximum 'spike' time?

Comment: @Cameron, I can't do that as some names could be 10 chars long and since the data is not null terminated I couldn't think of any other solution. If I make `name[11]` then the reading and cast to struct will get screwed.

Comment: @Naveen: You still can't put a null byte at `name[10]`, that's undefined behaviour and is almost certainly overwriting the low (or high if big endian) byte of `e`. You'll need to copy the bytes out into a larger buffer and put the null character there (obviously, only do this at the last minute when you need to actually print them out using c-strings -- otherwise, just keep them non-null terminated).

Comment: You are actually measuring the fluctuations of calling `chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` twice (and possibly the cost of cache misses when writing to `tmp->name[10]`). If these are the `clock_gettime` implementation, then you are likely to have a shared memory segment between kernel and user applications. This will lead to cache misses every time the clock changes. Even if you were able to reduce the jitter, this is probably not what you want to measure. `RDTSC` might be closer to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

> what can possibly cause this performance fluctuation: avg of 20 and
>   worst of 20,000?

On a PC (or Mac, or any desktop), there are Ethernet interrupts, timers, mem-refresh, and dozens of other things going on over which you have no (or very little) control.

You might consider changing the target.  If you use a single board computer (SBC) with only static ram, and a network connection which you can turn off and disconnect, and timers and clocks and every other kind of interrupt under your software control, you might achieve an acceptable result.

I once worked with a gal who wrote software for an 8085 SBC.  When we hooked up a scope and saw the waveform stability of a software controlled bit, I thought she must have added logic chips.  It was amazing.

You simply can not achieve 'jitter' free behaviour on a desktop.

Comment: It's not a desktop. It's an intel xeon ubuntu 14.04 server. But I guess ehternet jitters etc. would apply to it as well.