# Inconsistent chrono::high_resolution_clock delay

Tags: c++, delay, midi, c++-chrono

I'm trying to implement a MIDI-like clocked sample player.

There is a timer, which increments pulse counter, and every 480 pulses is a quarter, so pulse period is 1041667 ns for 120 beats per minute.
Timer is not sleep-based and running in separate thread, but it seems like delay time is inconsistent: period between samples played in a test file is fluctuating +- 20 ms (in some occasions period is OK and steady, I can't find out dependency of this effect).

Audio backend influence is excluded: i've tried OpenAL as well as SDL_mixer.

```
void Timer_class::sleep_ns(uint64_t ns){
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    bool sleep = true;

    while(sleep)
    {
        auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(now - start);
        if (elapsed.count() >= ns) {
                TestTime = elapsed.count();
                sleep = false;
                //break;
        }
    }
}

void Timer_class::Runner(void){
// this running as thread
    while(1){
        sleep_ns(BPMns);
        if (Run) Transport.IncPlaybackMarker(); // marker increment
        if (Transport.GetPlaybackMarker() == Transport.GetPlaybackEnd()){ // check if timer have reached end, which is 480 pulses
            Transport.SetPlaybackMarker(Transport.GetPlaybackStart());
            Player.PlayFile(1); // period of this event fluctuates severely 
        }
    }
};

void Player_class::PlayFile(int FileNumber){
    #ifdef AUDIO_SDL_MIXER
        if(Mix_PlayChannel(-1, WaveData[FileNumber], 0)==-1) {
        printf("Mix_PlayChannel: %s\n",Mix_GetError());
    }
    #endif // AUDIO_SDL_MIXER
}
```

Am i doing something wrong  in terms of an approach? Is there any better way to implement timer of this kind?
Deviation higher than 4-5 ms is too much in case of audio.

Comment: You are aware that you are (most likely) using a multi-tasking operating system? Your operating system can interrupt any process at any time, in order to switch the CPU to another background task, before resuming your process, are you aware of this? Expecting only a few milliseconds' worth of jitter, for your process, running on a general purpose operating system seems to be somewhat unrealistic. There are custom, special purpose, "real-time operating systems" that will guarantee real-time CPU to processes. If you need that much precision, you need to use a dedicated OS for that purpose.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Well I've assumed this possible based on existence of such software: digital audio workstations are already exist, and they're handling this kinds of consistent events completely fine even under consumer-grade OS. Multitasking, obviously, affects everything, but... 20 ms for 8 thread 4GHz CPU is way too much.

Comment: Their core logic is most likely written in hand-optimized C, or assembly language.

Comment: yeah but 20ms is not acceptable, thread scheduling is far more granular than that.

Comment: I would use `std::chrono::steady_clock` as the "high resolution" one is often just the system clock which is subject to external fluctuations.

Comment: Also why are you not using `std::this_thread::sleep_until`?

Comment: After you switch to `steady_clock` i think your delay should only be `+`, then you can write a piece of code to find that delay and subtract it from your spin time. `sleep_until` has no guarantees on next wake. A spin wait is the best way to go. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571180/how-to-guarantee-exact-thread-sleep-interval. CPU load will mess with it, but this is case with all DAW/DJ software running on Windows. If you want consistent audio processing, use a Mac as most DJs (like myself) do, and buy an external audio card designed for digital audio processing.

Comment: The very first DJ soundcard I bought used this driver, it's pretty much the best solution for windows apart from switching to core audio on mac. https://www.sweetwater.com/sweetcare/articles/installing-and-using-asio4all-for-windows/

Comment: @Avin Kavish, thanks, `steady_clock` works a bit better, at least measured time now is right (1041700) ns. 
But in output audio period is still 487ms or 511ms. No other values, only these two. It looks like something in code is eating up these 24 ms. I've tried to turn off GUI (curses). but it made no difference. 
At the end I hope to squeeze it into some single-board computer, since it's only a sample player.

Comment: @ub0baa: especially with Windows APIs, you can often observe some quantisation of time values that pretend to be in ns.  For example, if you write a busy loop that calls `high_resolution_clock::now()` or `steady_clock::now()`, you may well see the same value repeat many times then a sudden jump of as much as the 24ms you mention above, then that repeats for the same period and jumps again.  Ten lines of code and you can check whether this happens on your own box....

Comment: @AvinKavish There are also no guarantees when a spin-lock will terminate when running user code. I mean you may be correct in that it is the best way. But using `std::thread::sleep_until` on my system I am achieving an accuracy in the region of `0.08` of a millisecond (while compiling elsewhere).

Comment: yep, Howard's answer should do it as the loop is waiting **till** a time as opposed to **for** a time period, then the delay from the API calls shouldn't be a problem. But I have a feeling the API itself might be introducing a random delay internally which will still be a problem.

Comment: @Galik Oh that's interesting, I think I should do some experimentation myself. You do see the theory behind it right ? A spin-lock doesn't explicitly hand over control but `sleep_until` yields to the scheduler.

Comment: One can experiment with a continuum of spinning vs sleeping by sleeping until a some brief time until you're supposed to wake and then spinning until it is really time.  One can vary the "wake up early" amount from 0 to the entire time you're supposed to sleep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a large error and a small error.  The large error is that your code assumes that the main processing in `Runner` consistently takes zero time:

```
    if (Run) Transport.IncPlaybackMarker(); // marker increment
    if (Transport.GetPlaybackMarker() == Transport.GetPlaybackEnd()){ // check if timer have reached end, which is 480 pulses
        Transport.SetPlaybackMarker(Transport.GetPlaybackStart());
        Player.PlayFile(1); // period of this event fluctuates severely 
    }
```

That is, you're "sleeping" for the time you want your loop iteration to take, and then you're doing processing on top of that.

The small error is presuming that you can represent your ideal loop iteration time with an integral number of nanoseconds.  This error is so small that it doesn't really matter.  However I amuse myself by showing people how they can get rid of this error too. :-)

First lets correct the small error by *exactly* representing the idealized loop iteration time:

```
using quarterPeriod = std::ratio<1, 2>;
using iterationPeriod = std::ratio_divide<quarterPeriod, std::ratio<480>>;
using iteration_time = std::chrono::duration<std::int64_t, iterationPeriod>;
```

I know nothing of music, but I'm guessing the above code is right because if you convert `iteration_time{1}` to `nanoseconds`, you get approximately 1041667ns.  `iteration_time{1}` is intended to be the precise amount of time you want each iteration of your loop in `Timer_class::Runner` to take.

To correct the large error, you need to sleep *until* a `time_point`, as opposed to sleeping *for* a `duration`.  Here's a generic utility to help you do that:

```
template <class Clock, class Duration>
void
delay_until(std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration> tp)
{
    while (Clock::now() < tp)
        ;
}
```

Now if you code `Timer_class::Runner` to use `delay_until` instead of `sleep_ns`, I *think* you'll get better results:

```
void
Timer_class::Runner()
{
    auto next_start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + iteration_time{1};

    while (true)
    {
        if (Run) Transport.IncPlaybackMarker(); // marker increment
        if (Transport.GetPlaybackMarker() == Transport.GetPlaybackEnd()){ // check if timer have reached end, which is 480 pulses
            Transport.SetPlaybackMarker(Transport.GetPlaybackStart());
            Player.PlayFile(1);
        }
        delay_until(next_start);
        next_start += iteration_time{1};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using @howard-hinnant version of delay, and reducing buffer size in openal-soft, that's what made a huge difference, fluctuations is now about +-5 ms for 1/16th at 120BPM (125 ms period) and +-1 ms for quarter beats. Leaves a lot to be desired, but i guess it's okay